# How to float a window which has WM_NAME but no WM_CLASS

Tags: xmonad

### Configuration

Debian Linux 8.2, 64bit, Xmonad 0.11

### When it started

I recently upgraded my system (to debian8), so I had to make some adjustments to my `xmonad.hs` configuration - namely changing managehooks for GStreamer's`gst-launch` windows from:

```
, title     =? "gst-launch-0.10" --> doFloat
```

to:

```
, title     =? "gst-launch-1.0" --> doFloat
```

I'm using `title` instead of `className` because `gst-launch-1.0` windows have
only this properties:

```
$ xprop
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 6
WM_NAME(STRING) = "gst-launch-1.0"
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
                window state: Normal
                icon window: 0x0
_MOTIF_WM_HINTS(_MOTIF_WM_HINTS) = 0x2, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW
```

### What it does

I'm encountering very strange behaviour, which I haven't seen with the
old `gst-launch-0.10` windows. When `gst-launch-1.0` window (usually quite
small - 400x300) starts it is one of following cases with decreasing
probability:

- adds the window as another tile (no floating at all) and stretches its
  content to fill this tile (keeping aspect ratio), the rest of the tile is
  black
- adds the window as another tile (no floating at all) but draws only in the
  top left corner of this tile (no stretching), the rest of the tile shows
  X-Window background
- with less than 10% probability it floats the window properly

### What I've tried

`doFullFloat` and `doCenterFloat` do exactly the same thing (except it's
centered or full in the last case)

### What I suspect

I'm pretty sure the problem is in using only `WM_NAME/title` instead of
`WM_CLASS/className/appName`, because the title can be changed during the
lifetime of the window. I think the `gst-launch-1.0` window starts with some
other (or none) title and after some time it switches to `gst-launch-1.0`.
Then it's only matter of luck if `xmonad` catches the original title or the
final `gst-launch-1.0`.

### Question

Is there some way to "wait a while" in manageHook so I could be sure to catch
the final window `WM_NAME/title` ?

Or any other idea?

### Additional info:

Apparently this has been fixed in gstreamer - https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=750455 - but unfortunately I need to use gstreamer which comes with debian.

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpfull, the following is of type `X ()` so can be binded to a keybinding.

```haskell
withWindowSet
  $ (\ws -> case W.stack . W.workspace . W.current $ ws of
      Just w' ->
        mapM_
            (\w -> do
              s <- withDisplay
                $ \d -> fmap resClass $ liftIO $ getClassHint d w
              case (s) of
                "Emacs" -> do
                  windows $ W.focusWindow w
                "Lxterminal" -> do
                  wmName <- withDisplay
                    $ \d -> getStringProperty d w "WM_NAME"
                  case wmName of
                    Just "ranger" -> windows $ W.focusWindow w
            )
          $ W.integrate w'
      _ -> return ()
    )
```

The important lines are:

```haskell
"Lxterminal" -> do
  wmName <- withDisplay $ \d -> getStringProperty d w "WM_NAME"
    case wmName of
      Just "ranger" -> windows $ W.focusWindow w
```

So we first match by `WM_CLASS`, and then `WM_NAME`.